interpreting results of a prediction model
I have built a prediction model using a linear regression, my outcome is Activity of daily living (ADL) and I have included several predictors. Then I did a k-fold cross validation or leave-one-out cross validation looking into root mean squared error (RMSE). I need help to know how to interpret it? smaller RMSE shows a good prediction model? how is the good way to interpret it?
Additionally, how do we usually select variables in prediction model? and do I need to look at the normality of residuals in prediction model?
Here is the Table result:

With only 60 observations, as shown in your model summary, I fear that you have an overfit model. Even with a small root mean square error (RMSE) on this data set, it's unlikely that the same model would have a small RMSE on another data sample. Neither leave-one-out cross validation (CV) nor a single 5-fold CV can check that well. A rule of thumb to avoid overfitting is that you need about 15 observations per coefficient you are estimating. With 60 observations, that's only 4 coefficients. You are estimating ~15.

then what should I do to avoid overfitting and answer my question? I am looking to see if these variables can predict ADL. how about excluding some of the variables? what would be the best to do that? can I look at the correlation matrix?

Chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies is a good resource on that. If you can't get more observations (the best choice), you have 2 general types of approaches. You can try to combine related predictors without using information from the outcomes, what Prof. Harrell calls "data reduction." Or you can use some form of "penalized" regression that down-weights the magnitudes of the regression coefficients in a way that recognizes potential overfitting; ridge regression might be a good choice for that approach here.

just a question: since this is a prediction model not assumption, is'nt that I do NOT need to check the multicollinearity? isn't that these variables may contribute to the prediction model? also I cannot look at the p-value like association, am I right?

Multicollinearity isn’t the issue here. Even if all of the predictors were independently distributed, there would still be a problem with the predictive quality of a model based on not enough observations relative to the number of predictors.

I see. thank you. Can I ask then how to interpret the results from prediction model? just assuming the above model is fine then how can I interpret the results from prediction model? also, based on the number of obs = 60, you suggest 4 predictors to include using the linear regression? what if I get a high RMSE (poor) from using 4 predictors?

thanks. Do you have any suggestion for doing penalized regression in stata? if i can replace with my analysis?

Try a web search for something like "ridge regression Stata"; see this web page as one result. I don't use Stata, and highly software-specific questions without statistical content are off-topic on this site.

Big picture
With a predictive model and a continuous outcome, what matters is the root mean square error (RMSE; or a similar metric) on new data samples. With a sufficiently complicated model you can get down close to 0 RMSE for the data set you used to build the model. Such a model typically performs very poorly on new data samples. This is related to the bias-variance tradeoff inherent in statistical modeling. See Section 2.2.2 of An Introduction to Statistical Learning.
Neither leave-one-out cross validation (CV) nor a single 5-fold CV will help much for documenting that type of overfitting. A less-overfit model (here, about 4 predictors with unpenalized coefficients given 60 observations, or more predictors with penalized coefficients equivalent to about 4 unpenalized coefficients) might have worse RMSE on this data set but would be expected to perform better on new data. See Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies for ways to build models with limited data.
Stata model report on regression model
This UCLA web page goes into much more detail about using and interpreting Stata for regression models than can easily fit here. Basically, if I understand the Stata coding correctly, the _const is the expected outcome when continuous predictors have values of 0 and categorical predictors are at their reference levels. The individual regression coefficients are the changes from that outcome per unit change in a continuous predictor or for a switch from the reference level of a categorical predictor to a different level. Each P > |t| value is the probability that the corresponding coefficient has a value different from 0. By the usual criterion of P < 0.05, only 2 of your coefficients are "significantly different from 0," but with an overfit model like this I wouldn't pay much attention to the coefficients or to their P values.
Specifics of your model
Your outcome is related to activities of daily living (ADL), presumably a continuous measure related to how well an individual can take care of himself or herself without assistance. One of your predictors, the HAQ Score, however, seems to be based on a questionnaire asking an individual how successfully ADL have been accomplished recently. It's not clear what's gained by including this highly similar measure of ADL in a model trying to predict ADL.
